# Bitcoin QT Rpc Transaction date format

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, json-rpc

I am trying to get information about my transactions from my wallet,

I use Listtransactions, and get all the information, but the time/blocktime/receivetime - there are all in number i can't decipher "1390424516" i thought they were ticks, but new DateTime(1390424516) gets me 01/01/0001 00:02:19 ...
I tried using them as seconds, i got to year 0045...

the documentations says 
"time" : time associated with the transaction[1].
From block timestamp, unless transaction was already in memory pool then the local time when the client added the transaction to its memory pool

so i tried both methods on Blocktime too, but can't figure out how to get the time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Unix date format. As I understand, you are using c#, so it will be look like:

```
public static DateTime FromUnixTime(uint time)
{
    return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(time);
}
```